# Get the exact character index in the google docs irrespective of number of Pages rendered

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

**Issue Summary:**

Find exact index of user’s caret position in a large google doc.

**Issue Details:**

A google doc is basically a web page. Made of html, css and javascript.
When you click inside a google doc, the caret goes to the click position immediately.

In a google doc of say just 1 page, it is possible to get the exact index of the user’s caret position. All that is needed to be done is to traverse the DOM elements, get all the text into a string and find out the index of the caret inside that string.

But in case of larger google docs (say one with 20 pages), not all text is loaded into the doc on document load. Only the first page is fully rendered in the DOM and the rest of the content is rendered progressively as the user scrolls down the doc.

If you scroll fast to say the 10th page, the 10th page’s content is fully rendered. But the text in pages before that is not rendered. Because of this, getting the correct index of the caret in the 10th page is not possible. If you extract all text from the doc by traversing the DOM and try to find the index, it will always be wrong (As a lot of text before the caret in the doc has never been rendered).

From our R&D, we know that google doc does store the index of every character in the doc somewhere. We know this because if you type a character in the 10th page, an API call is made immediately and this API call has the correct character index in it.You can see this API call in chrome browser’s network tab.

The API URL is like this:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rt2aOa9_nAWGAQQGZWWzEPxnVihWpC0Ejv1ghh69KM9o4/save?id=1rt2aOa9_nAWGAQQGZWWzEPxnVihWpC0Ejv1x_aWKM9o&sid=7bb6f7c06b7ab1ef&vc=1&c=1&w=1&flr=0&smv=8&token=AC4w5VhH-UTBlVwVdFQIbjS77y8mchf4Zw%3A1596552882670&includes_info_params=true

As you can see from the above pasted URL, the API URL ends with the word “save”. It is a POST api and the index can be seen in the posted JSON body. The JSON key containing the index is named “si”.
What we don’t know is where it is stored and how to get to it.

**Solution Required:**

Need a Javascript code snippet that can be pasted into the console of chrome developer tools.
Basically, I scroll quickly to the 10th page of say a 20 page doc, click somewhere on that page,  and then paste your code snippet in the console and that should give us the correct character index of the caret. Of course the doc shouldn’t be fully force rendered by slowly scrolling through the pages manually.

**Additional Details:**
Chrome is the only browser that we need the solution for. Other browsers can be ignored.
The reason why we are asking for a code snippet that can be pasted into the console of  chrome developer tools is because we are building a chrome extension and any code that runs in the console can be used inside our chrome extension easily.

**References:**
Refer to the googleDocsUtil.js file at: https://github.com/JensPLarsen/ChromeExtension-GoogleDocsUtil/tree/master/sample-extension . This file has code to get the index from a google doc. It is pretty good but fails in large docs where all pages before the clicked character have not been rendered.
Refer to this great article on reverse engineering of a google doc: https://features.jsomers.net/how-i-reverse-engineered-google-docs/

Comment: Indexes in Docs API are relative to the element of which they are part. Could you please provide more information in order to clarify your question? What do you want to do with this index? Also, you say you want to get the index of the clicked character, but Docs API doesn't have selection properties (selection means there is a UI involved). I think you would need to use Apps Script for this, would that be appropriate for you?

Comment: With every character in google doc, there is a timestamp attached with it. When you check in detail, google keeps the revision of the whole doc. I have bigger document and if i direct go to the page 130, and click on any of the word. I want to know the timepstamp for it. 

To get the timestamp, google API is helping me, provided i should pass the exact index of the character. 

My i am saying exact is because what you said, its relative to the number of element and contents rendered in the document